# Variable Selection : Removing Linear Dependency by SVD using the Condition number and then eliminating the variable causing multicollinearity

Tags: regression, python, feature-selection, svd, condition-number

I am trying to perform regression with over 5000 feature variables(X) and I would like to eliminate multicollinearity.  Incremental VIF computation is expensive. Incremental PCA works but I might lose out on an independent variable that has good  correlation with my Y variable. I would like to get back a truncated version of my feature variable matrix. Is there a way to do this in python ?

Answer (score 1):

PCA routines typically work by performing SVD first so if PCA won't work for you there's a good chance that neither will SVD. Remember that incremental PCA incrementally processes the records; not the variables, so you'll keep all your variables. However, because you're processing records in batches you will lose some precision.

scikit learn comes with a decent incremental PCA routine:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_incremental_pca.html

It has a batch size parameter which lets you control how many records are processed simultaneously.

Comment: I am not looking for a PCA solution(incremental or otherwise) because PCA is designed to project onto the axis explaining the max variance of the data ( the predictors - X). A relatively independent variable which has good correlation with the Y variable might not represent itself in any of the major principal components. 

I am looking at something similar to a VIF based elimination of the original column vectors but that is based on condition number ( which is obtained via SVD), and less expensive that VIF